# Using MVCSiteMap when loading site into a container

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

We currently load our sites content into a container on the  main page and never reload the whole site. We use jqAddress for deep linking. I've been tasked with creating a bread crumb solution to use on the site and looked at MVCSiteMap as a solution. The problem is that whenwe load the content into the container and change the address the site map bread crumb isn't updating because the page isn't re-rendering, we are simply loading the partial inside a view container. My idea was to create another partial and have the jqAddress change event reload the partial, but I'm not sure how to get all the data to the SiteMap helpers to tell it where we just went so it can properly generate the breadcrumb path. Any help/ideas would be very much obliged.

Thanks in advance,

Austin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that the easiest way to fix this is to just include the site map path on every page that gets loaded into the view container. This will cause it to render the path properly. Now I just have to delve into the depths of the mysteries of dynamic node providers!